# Инспекция кода на возможные блокировки и время выполнения

Tags: golang, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. Снова ищу опытных разработчиков, которые могу ткнуть меня носом в косяки алгоритма. Суть алгоритма в прослушивании канала сигналов системе и выполнеии пользовательских функций в зависимоти от поступившего сигнала. Пользователем выступает программист, который может использовать функцию в своем коде.

Вот сама функция

```
package capturesig

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

//signals capturing
func Capture_signals(target_signal os.Signal, sigchan chan os.Signal, target_sig interface{}, default_sig interface{}) {
    signal.Notify(sigchan)
    current_sig := <-sigchan
    switch current_sig {
    case target_signal:
        target := target_sig.(func(...interface{}))
        go target()
    default:
        def := default_sig.(func(...interface{}))
        go def()
    }
}
```

А [здесь](https://github.com/udonetsm/capturesig) пример использования в папке example.

Comment: зачем что-то менять, если все работает? os.Signal можно получить в разных частях вашего приложения. но если все оставить, то я бы передавал вместо interface-a `target_sig interface{}` что-то вроде `target_sig func()`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Простой func не предполагает входящих аргументов, а функции обычно имею аргументы(не всегда конечно, но чаще всего). Я думал сделать строгие аргументы типа arg1 string, arg2 int или что-то подобное, но передумал, потому что ее можно применять где угодно и строгие аргументы ее ограничивают. А так можно аргементы указать а можно и не указать. Но правда и обрабатывать аргументы, забота программиста, который функцию может вызвать(по циклу аргументы прогнать или обработать определенный элемент массива аргументов).
А так я спросил, все ли я учел(блокировки) и нет ли косяков)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Я просто занялся интерфейсами (в папке примеров) и каналами только сейчас, до последнего их откладывал. Поэтому сомневаюсь что все правильно делаю, сомневаюсь что правильно с ними работаю)

Comment: но вы можете обернуть все что хотите в func() и передать в качестве аргумента. а детали с аргументами будут внутри. тогда это будет более удобный вариант.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Аа, как мидлварь?

Answer (score 1):

смылс в том, чтобы вызываемые функции были простыми. вы сами можете добавить внутри все, что захотите. и не нужно будет кастить, так как вы точно ожидаете func()

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestConfig(t *testing.T) {
    sigschan := make(chan os.Signal)

    go func() {
        t.Logf("поехали")
        sigschan <- syscall.SIGINT
    }()

    another_one := func() {
        fmt.Println("я могу делать все, что захочу")
        def("1")
    }

    Capture_signals(syscall.SIGINT, sigschan, func() { target(1, 2, 3) }, another_one)

    t.Log("вторая попытка")
    go func() { sigschan <- syscall.SIGABRT }()
    t.Log("поехали!")
    Capture_signals(syscall.SIGINT, sigschan, func() { target(1, 2, 3) }, another_one)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}

type caller func()

func Capture_signals(target_signal os.Signal, sigchan chan os.Signal, target_sig caller, default_sig caller) {
    signal.Notify(sigchan)
    current_sig := <-sigchan
    switch current_sig {
    case target_signal:
        go target_sig()
    default:
        go default_sig()
    }
}

func target(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Found interrupt")
    // os.Exit(int(syscall.SIGINT))
}

func def(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("default ")
}
```

```
=== RUN   TestConfig
    t_test.go:16: поехали
Found interrupt
    t_test.go:27: вторая попытка
    t_test.go:29: поехали!
я могу делать все, что захочу
default 
--- PASS: TestConfig (1.00s)
```

Comment: Вот теперь понял. Делать переменную типа функции.

Comment: Но тогда не передать аргументы в функции traget и def

Comment: переменную я создал просто для удобства